# mapping not updating after function call

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

```
    struct allowanceInfo {
     address allowedAddress;
     bool isAllowed;
     }

    mapping(address => allowanceInfo) public allowed;

    function allow() public { 
        require(msg.sender == allowanceInfo[allowedAddress].allowedAddress);
        allowanceInfo[allowedAddress].isAllowed == true;
        }
```

Why is my mapping not updating the boolean value of my isAllowed variable, when I look up the allowedAddress in the mapping?

Comment: `allowanceInfo[allowedAddress].allowedAddress` raises an eyebrow...

Comment: I'm not sure why.

Comment: Well, it won't compile to begin with  (`allowedAddress` is not defined).

Comment: Sounds like all you need is `mapping(address => bool) public allowed` and `require(allowed[msg.sender])`, but I'm probably missing some context (which you did not bother to specify in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a potential syntax/logic mistake. Intuitively you might try something like (even if it isn't very clear):

```
  struct allowanceInfo {
     address allowedAddress;
     bool isAllowed;
 }

 mapping(address => allowanceInfo) public allowed;
 modifier onlyAllowedAddress(require(msg.sender == allowed[msg.sender].allowedAddress); _;)

 function allow() public onlyAllowedAddress() { 
     allowed[msg.sender].isAllowed = true;
 }
```

to get a mapping value I had to specify its name "allowed" and an address between brackets in order to get the relative "allowanceInfo" struct

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what you are trying to do here, you are treating the structure as a mapping. Is the function suppose to check if the msg.sender is allowed? if so, then:

```
mapping(address => bool) public allowed;
function allow() public returns(bool){`
    return allowed[msg.sender];
}`
```

Hope it helps